# jQuery GET Rails controller method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, get, rails-routing

How does jQuery `.get()` work with Rails methods? I've set up a method in a `documents` controller called `templates` and I'd like to access that method from a JS method in a separate JS file. From doing some research I found that using `.get()` is the best way to access Rails methods, but when I do, for instance, `var templates = $.get("/documents#templates", function (data) { console.log(data) }`, it's just console logging the entire `/documents` HTML DOM structure.

I'm guessing I need to "hijack" the route if you will, but I tried adding a custom route and the console log is still returning the HTML page, not even reaching my Rails controller.

If it helps (although I doubt it, since removing this entirely doesn't alter the console log results), here's my `templates` method in the controller:

```
def templates
  @templates = DocumentTemplate.all
  @output = []
  @templates.each do |template|
    @output = template.content
  end
  respond_with(@output)
end
```

Comment: Just spotted that you need to specify a URL for the first argument to $.get, like 'documents/templates', rather than the Rails controller mapping ('documents#templates'). To find the URL run `rake routes` in your console or specify the path explicitly in routes.rb (e.g. `get 'documents/templates', to: 'documents#templates'`).

Comment: Thank you! Declaring the path in ```routes.rb``` plus @Oli's method below works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to respond to jQuery's GET request with snippets of HTML you could consider rendering a [partial layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) (which won't include the full application layout). In your controller the response may look like:

```
def templates
  @templates = DocumentTemplate.all

  if request.xhr?
    render :partial => 'templates', locals: {:templates => @templates}
  else
    # respond with your normal layout if required
  end
end
```

Then in your `app/views/documents/` folder create a partial file called `_templates.html.haml` (or .erb). Note the leading underscore in partial names.

You'll have access to a `templates` local variable to loop over in your partial file (syntax here is for HAML):

```
- templates.each do |template|
   # do what's required to present each template instance here
```

Then your jQuery GET request should receive just the partial snippets of HTML:

```
$.get("/documents/templates", function(data) {
  console.log('data');
  alert("Load was performed.");
});
```

Comment: Sorry on my delay in responding, but thanks a lot for the explanation. It makes sense what you explained, but I am getting a 404 error in the console because it can't find ```/documents/templates```. I would need to modify my routes, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to return? There are a few different approaches, depending on your needs.

`$(data).find('selector')` is the least elegant way. You can extract what you need from the full response with jQuery.

`respond_with(@output, :layout => !request.xhr? )` will render the page without the surrounding application.html file. The following is a way to render a different partial for jQuery.

```
respond_with(@output) do |format|
  format.html { render partial: 'templates' if request.xhr? }
end
```

You could also send back JSON easily enough if that's what you require. There's a nice blog post here about various approaches to Rails AJAX: http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html

Comment: The problem is that the full response is not what it's supposed to be. The response is supposed to return the ```content``` value of each ```template``` instance. But ```.get()``` is not even reaching the Rails method...that's the real problem here.